# trignometry related question

Tags: trigonometric-series

At point the angle of elevation of the top of a tower is such that its tangent is 5/12 . On walking 80m towards the tower, the cotangent of the angle of elevation of the top of the tower is 4/3. The height of the tower is how much m?

Comment: Try to draw a diagram and then attempt your question.

Answer (score 0):

Survey formula:

$$\frac{S(\tan a_1.\tan a_2)}{(\tan a_1-\tan a_2)}$$

$$\frac{80(3/4)(5/12)}{(\frac34-\frac5{12})}= 75  \space\text{ m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the information given, you can derive the following two equations:
$$
(i):\; \frac{h}{x} = \frac{5}{12}\\
(ii):\;\frac{h}{x-80} = \frac{3}{4}
$$

Solving (i) for x, (ii) for h, and combining both gives
$$
(i):\; x = h\frac{12}{5}\\
(ii):\; h = (x-80)\frac{3}{4}\\
(i+ii):\; h = (h\frac{12}{5}-80)\frac{3}{4}\\
h = h\frac{9}{5}-60\\
h = \frac{60}{\frac{9}{5}-1} = 300/4 = 75
$$

So the height is 75m.